# Antimalware and Onedrive services uses up a lot of CPU time

Tags: windows-10

Ever since upgrading to Windows 10 1903 the other day, my CPUs have all been pegged at 100%.  "Antimalware Service Executable" is using 60%, and "Microsoft OneDrive (32 bit)" is using 35% (with the other 5% being spread amongst everything else running).  After running like this for a day or so my computer case (Surface Tablet) is smoking hot.

How can I find out what's causing this problem?  Is there logging I can review for those services?  Known issues with 1903 that I just can't find on Google?

Comment: can you file a feedback from this PC using the Feedback Hub app? File the feedback under "Files, Folders, and Online Storage" with subcategory "OneDrive"

Comment: @user1574981 Done.  5 days later and it's the same, hope it's something Microsoft will fix.  Not only is the computer case super hot, but it does makes some apps a little laggy...

Comment: there is a [followup question](https://superuser.com/questions/1503501/antimalware-service-executable-disk-usage-continually-runs-at-100) on disc usage as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling my 3rd party (ESET) Antivirus got that Windows Defender/antimalware service back under control.  Must have been some kind of conflict there.

For OneDrive, "%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset" immediately dropped the high CPU usage from my OneDrive service.  It did cause a full resync though, so ran a long time and used a lot of bandwidth.  For me it maintained my list of folders to sync, but I've read elsewhere that it may not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this helped:

- My OneDrive server is behind my company firewall, so when I am working remotely, and if the VPN is not on, then high CPU may result, so connecting to the VPN can help; but just that alone may not be enough
- There might be some issues that have accumulated since the last successful VPN connection, so I may also need to go clear the issues (click the little OneDrive icon and click the appropriate buttons to retry sync and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Use **MpCmdRun** command-line tool to configure and manage Microsoft Defender Antivirus.

Make a batch file and run it:

```
powershell Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender' -Force
powershell Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Defender' -Force
powershell Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender' -Force
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender"
MpCmdRun -GetFiles
explorer "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Support"
```

The 1st three lines add Windows Defender folders to Windows Defender exclusions.

```
powershell Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender' -Force
powershell Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Defender' -Force
powershell Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender' -Force
```

No reboot required, that should solve Windows Defender high CPU usage.

This line:

```
MpCmdRun.exe -GetFiles
```

creates a MPSupportFiles.cab file which gathers the following log files and packages them together in a compressed file in the support directory:

```
- Any trace files from Microsoft Antimalware Service
- The Windows Update history log
- All Microsoft Antimalware Service events from the System event log
- All relevant Microsoft Antimalware Service registry locations
- The log file of this tool
- The log file of the signature update helper tool
```

When File Explorer opens:

> 1. Open the MPSupportFiles.cab
> 2. Select all
> 3. Right click
> 4. Copy or extract to whatever folder you like

Now you have all Windows Defender log files which you can load in Event Viewer.

You can open the MPSupportFiles.cab with 7-Zip also.

MpCmdRun Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/command-line-arguments-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).