# "Antimalware Service Executable" disk usage continually runs at 100%

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

Antimalware Service Executable (Win10) has had disk usage pegged at 100% for five hours and counting. Is there any way to get some level of detail what specifically it's doing and/or an estimate of when it will be done?

This seems pretty basic but every search I've tried yields piles and piles of "solutions" that involve disabling the service. I don't want to do that. What is Antimalware Service Executable actually doing? What other solutions are there to fix the problem?

**Edit:** Explanation of why it is not a duplicate question:

The single answer on the "[duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1440453/why-are-the-antimalware-and-onedrive-services-out-of-control)" is installing a different antivirus program. That's not in any sense an answer for how to find out what Antimalware Service Executable is doing.

**Edit:** I did not change the subject and I don't think it reflects the question. I am not asking how to make the process stop having high disk usage. I'm asking how to get some information about what the process is currently doing instead of just guessing.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question not for the OPs reason but because the other question is about CPU time and not about disc usage. I changed both titles accordingly.

Comment: That sounds like it's doing a full system scan, as it should run at ~100% after login, but should taper off after a few min (~5min at most with a SSD). Are you utilizing a mechanical HDD or a SSD and what effect does a reboot have?  if the former, the best solution would be to simply upgrade to a SSD due to the IOPS, which would solve the 100% disk access for-long-periods-of-time issue by this specific service.

Comment: Mechanical HDD. This persisted for about 48 hours. Is there a way to check if a scan is running? When this was happening I tried looking in Task Scheduler under Microsoft => Windows Defender and none of the tasks had a Running status.

Answer (score 0):

Use **MpCmdRun.exe** command-line tool to configure and manage Microsoft Defender Antivirus.

Make a batch file and run it:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender"
MpCmdRun -GetFiles
explorer "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Support"
```

The line:

```
MpCmdRun -GetFiles
```

creates a MPSupportFiles.cab file which gathers the following log files and packages them together in a compressed file in the support directory:

```
- Any trace files from Microsoft Antimalware Service
- The Windows Update history log
- All Microsoft Antimalware Service events from the System event log
- All relevant Microsoft Antimalware Service registry locations
- The log file of this tool
- The log file of the signature update helper tool
```

When File Explorer opens:

> 1. Open the MPSupportFiles.cab
> 2. Select all
> 3. Right click
> 4. Copy or extract to whatever folder you like

Now you have all Windows Defender log files which you can load in Event Viewer.

You can open the MPSupportFiles.cab with 7-Zip also.

MpCmdRun Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/command-line-arguments-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide